# Flatten dictionary with repeated values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, flatten

Looking for the most efficient way without looping...
Given the below Python(2.7) Dictionary:

```
l = [{
"General": {
    "Iteration": {
        "CATID": 74470
    }
},
"Return": {
    "Effectiveness": {
        "Metrics": [{
            "Volume": 1004287.8947531971,
            "BusinessMetricID": 1,
            "ImpactScore": 0.032579772546071015,
            "GrossMargin": 10042878.94753197,
            "Revenue": 20085757.89506394
        },
        {
            "Volume": 2678101.0526751927,
            "BusinessMetricID": 2,
            "ImpactScore": 0.08687939345618939,
            "GrossMargin": 6695252.631687982,
            "Revenue": 13390505.263375964
        }]
    }
}
},
{
"General": {
    "Iteration": {
        "CATID": 74471
    }
},
"Return": {
    "Effectiveness": {
        "Metrics": [{
            "Volume": 1004287.8947531971,
            "BusinessMetricID": 1,
            "ImpactScore": 0.032579772546071015,
            "GrossMargin": 10042878.94753197,
            "Revenue": 20085757.89506394
        },
        {
            "Volume": 2678101.0526751927,
            "BusinessMetricID": 2,
            "ImpactScore": 0.08687939345618939,
            "GrossMargin": 6695252.631687982,
            "Revenue": 13390505.263375964
        }]
    }
}
}]
```

I'm trying to flatten the metrics list of lists while adding the CATID property to get the following list of dictionaries

```
[{
"CATID": 74470,    
"Volume": 35399.19921217802,
"BusinessMetricID": 1,
"ImpactScore": 0.015,
"GrossMargin": 353991.9921217802,
"Revenue": 707983.9842435603
},
{
"CATID": 74470,
"Volume": 94397.86456580806,
"BusinessMetricID": 2,
"ImpactScore": 0.04,
"GrossMargin": 235994.66141452017,
"Revenue": 471989.32282904035
},
{
"CATID": 74471,    
"Volume": 35399.19921217802,
"BusinessMetricID": 1,
"ImpactScore": 0.015,
"GrossMargin": 353991.9921217802,
"Revenue": 707983.9842435603
},
{
"CATID": 74471,
"Volume": 94397.86456580806,
"BusinessMetricID": 2,
"ImpactScore": 0.04,
"GrossMargin": 235994.66141452017,
"Revenue": 471989.32282904035
}
]
```

What's the most efficient way to do that? I tried to use list comprehension but I can't find a way to add the extra property. 
To simply flatten the metrics I've used:

```
[item for sublist in [x['Return']['Effectiveness']['Metrics'] for x in l] for item in sublist]
```

which gives me:

```
[{
'Volume': 1004287.8947531971,
'BusinessMetricID': 1,
'ImpactScore': 0.032579772546071015,
'GrossMargin': 10042878.94753197,
'Revenue': 20085757.89506394
 },
{
'Volume': 2678101.0526751927,
'BusinessMetricID': 2,
'ImpactScore': 0.08687939345618939,
'GrossMargin': 6695252.631687982,
'Revenue': 13390505.263375964
 },
 {
'Volume': 1004287.8947531971,
'BusinessMetricID': 1,
'ImpactScore': 0.032579772546071015,
'GrossMargin': 10042878.94753197,
'Revenue': 20085757.89506394
 },
 {
'Volume': 2678101.0526751927,
'BusinessMetricID': 2,
'ImpactScore': 0.08687939345618939,
'GrossMargin': 6695252.631687982,
'Revenue': 13390505.263375964
 }]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think experts can provide even better solution.
Here is my solution. You can look out for itertools module.

```
from itertools import product, chain
nl = chain.from_iterable([ product( i['General']['Iteration'].items(), [ j.items() for j in i['Return']['Effectiveness']['Metrics'] ]) for i in l ])
[ dict([i] + list(j)) for i,j in nl ]
```

Output:

```
[{'BusinessMetricID': 1,
  'CATID': 74470,
  'GrossMargin': 10042878.94753197,
  'ImpactScore': 0.032579772546071015,
  'Revenue': 20085757.89506394,
  'Volume': 1004287.8947531971},
 {'BusinessMetricID': 2,
  'CATID': 74470,
  'GrossMargin': 6695252.631687982,
  'ImpactScore': 0.08687939345618939,
  'Revenue': 13390505.263375964,
  'Volume': 2678101.0526751927},
 {'BusinessMetricID': 1,
  'CATID': 74471,
  'GrossMargin': 10042878.94753197,
  'ImpactScore': 0.032579772546071015,
  'Revenue': 20085757.89506394,
  'Volume': 1004287.8947531971},
 {'BusinessMetricID': 2,
  'CATID': 74471,
  'GrossMargin': 6695252.631687982,
  'ImpactScore': 0.08687939345618939,
  'Revenue': 13390505.263375964,
  'Volume': 2678101.0526751927}]
```